# Windows OpenSSH ignoring UserKnownHostsFile option?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I'm running a command-line version of openssh on windows and passing the `UserKnownHostsFile` option to have it check for host keys somewhere other than the home directory. For some reason, it appears that openssh is ignoring this option:

`ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=yes" -o UserKnownHostsFile="C:\Users\Tim\hostkey.txt" host`

results in the following log:

`Could not create directory '/home/Tim/.ssh'.
No RSA host key is known for [host]:22 and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.`

Any ideas why it wouldn't pick up the option I requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get this CLI tool?  Is it cygwin based, or what?  My guess is that it isn't recognizing `C:\Users\Tim\hostkey.txt` as a valid directory name, and you need to use something like `/cygdrive/c/Users/Tim/hostkey.txt` or something else depending on the specific variant of the ssh client build.

Also, try adding a `-v` to your ssh command, it should print out more verbose errors and status.

Comment: or maybe the whole parameter should be in quotation marks? like `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=yes" -o "UserKnownHostsFile=C:\Users\Tim\hostkey.txt" host`

Comment: It could have come from Git Bash.